# Feeling embarrassed after purchasing a gift for a co-worker as an apology

Tags: communication, colleagues, meetings

I purchased a co-worker a statue of a bear riding a bicycle, for some reason, as an apology for being late to a meeting. He decided to put it, and the note I wrote introducing the bear, on the table where we do standup with the team.

I don't want it to be there. I am feeling embarrassed that I got him the thing, because it was a weird thing to do, and I don't want to explain it. I expected him to take it home when I got it, and keep it between us.

I have half a mind to steal the statue back before the standup on Monday. What should I do?

Comment: Does a bear riding a bicycle mean... how does... is there... nevermind. I have too many questions about this post to put into one comment...

Comment: Have you thought about coworkers in your company are not allowed to gift each other?

Comment: Who cares? I think you are making a problem where there is none

Comment: Nuke it from space.

Comment: Do you normally give people gifts as apologies?

Comment: This could turn into an amusing good-natured custom in your group. The one who's late gets the bear. Go with it!

Answer (score 16):

> What should I do?

If you are not comfortable with him putting the Bear there, I suggest you approach him and tell him about it.

Try in his office, or wherever you seem fit, and ask for a quick private talk. Express to him that the gift was intended for him as an apology, and that it is embarrassing for you that it is displayed in front of everybody.

Any sane person would see that this is causing you discomfort, and remove the bear or take it to their home. The point is that if you don't communicate it it will never happen.

Comment: That sounds very reasonable. Unfortunatly we do not have offices, but I will do the equivilent for what you suggest for my workplace layout. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help, good luck with that.

Answer (score 6):

DarkCygnus answer is good if you really don't want anyone else to see the bear, but if you want to minimize perceived weirdness from other people you should probably just suck it up. The gift sounds a little bit quirky, but also funny and nice. Stealing it back or even just being embarrassed about it later would likely be seen as **a lot** weirder than giving the gift in the first place.

Answer (score 5):

The next time you’re late to a meeting, as an apology you should say “sorry I’m late for the meeting”. That’s it. No presents. Ever.